# how to pass JSONArray to the controller from ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc in java. I am trying to pass a List from javascript to controller as a JSONArray. But the controller get it as [] or null.

Can anyone help me in passing the list of Object using Jquery ajax call and how to get this value in controller. I can able to pass the JSONArray using Ajax but can't read it in controller.

Thanks
Sandy

Comment: can you post the content of the request body?

Answer (score 0):

you can post using ajax by following way

```
  $.post("/Home/SaveData/", { jsonData: jlst },
    function(data, textStatus) {
    if (textStatus != "success") {
    result = "false";
    }
    });
    }
```

you need to build method in home controller to handle this as per below

```
  public ActionResult SaveData(string jsonData)
    {}
```

for complete demo refer below links

http://krishnarajb.wordpress.com/2009/05/28/pass-json-object-from-javascript-code-to-mvc-controller/

http://erraticdev.blogspot.in/2010/12/sending-complex-json-objects-to-aspnet.html

Comment: Thanks Arun for your quick reply. I tried this code but in the controller the string I am getting as null.

jsonData:[{"id": 1, "name": "ABCD", "email": "abcd@one.com"}, {"id": 2, "name": "EFGH", "email": "efgh@one.com"}, {"id": 3, "name": "IJKL", "email": "ijkl@one.com"}, {"id": 4, "name": "MNOP", "email": "mnop@one.com"}]

This is the value that my ajax is passing.
Do you have idea what i am doing wrong in this?

Comment: Take this array in var obj and convert to json using var jlst = $.toJSON(obj); and pass as jsonData: jlist